# Libreoffice in Ubuntu not converting symbols in ppt slide

Tags: ubuntu, microsoft-powerpoint, libreoffice

I have a software which uses libreoffice to convert documents to pdf. I ran into a bug where I uploaded one of my course's slides and some mathematical symbols were removed and not displayed

I opened the file in libreoffice desktop (in Ubuntu) and the problem existed.

[The symbols which are supposed to be](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rFHx1.png)

[What I get when i open the file in libreoffice](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pqRNQ.png)

[The ppt file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1BcInRDx3Mzfp47i1nfn9L3AV4a10PB72/view?usp=share_link)

I tried installing new fonts.
I tried using other office suites like wpsoffice, onlyoffice. They worked fine with few mistakes but all the symbols were present

Comment: This is not a problem with LibreOffice, but with PowerPoint. Just look at the tables on [**this page**](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/use-powerpoint-to-save-or-open-a-presentation-in-the-opendocument-presentation-odp-format-94805e84-1b09-4c98-a8b5-0da2a52242a0) - see how many items are marked "Not supported" or "Partially supported"?The best option for you would be to use PowerPoint's capabilities to save your presentation in PDF format, Impress will do well with your lectures only if you initially make a presentation using it. After all, no one promised 100% compatibility, right?

Comment: It works absolutely fine in powerpoint, wpsoffice, openoffice.

Comment: Sorry, but for me, OpenOffIce "loses" special characters in the same way, plus it also distorts the layout, ignores dark theme, shifts elements

Comment: what can be the solution for libreoffice issue? is it os issue or anything else?

Comment: Try one of [**the online converters**](https://www.google.com/search?q=convert+pptx+to+pdf). I took [**the first one**](https://www.ilovepdf.com/download/h6sjd7n3wnmrh5qly49jzwm0yqtxqzsbAbrcznwp69h840p7f9r0r6lsldrcjbbjArtb60tfnlpt49vmhA954bpnld2xqz6v77jvywk1wszq0clc94xyzwl3bbApn042r4n70tr28jw08lkzgl7q8gbpk6pcly9ny16lg8s13k3x0yl7383dndkzr6vv0jjr21zl53g2pw2qq/24w) that came across and got a pretty decent result (this is not an advertisement, I really chosen at random)

Comment: yeah online converters are great I have tried them, but I am using libreoffice in my app.

Comment: In this case, you simply document for your application that this part is only partially implemented until [**#TDF129061**](https://bugs.documentfoundation.org/show_bug.cgi?id=129061) will be fixed.